# Why am I being told a class does not exist in my namespace when it does?

Tags: windows-store-apps, custom-controls, winrt-xaml, xml-namespaces, resourcedictionary

I am trying to follow [the article here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/99bb20/custom-control-in-windows-8-apps-using-C-Sharp/) to add a custom control to my project so that I can call it ("promptForPhotosetName") like so:

```
Popup popTart = new Popup();
popTart.Child = new promptForPhotosetName();
popTart.IsOpen = true;
```

I added a Custom Control to my project based on Templated Control.

My custom control class (which IS in the Photrax namespace) contains this constructor:

```
public promptForPhotosetName()
{
    this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(promptForPhotosetName);
}
```

I have this in \Themes\Generic.xaml, which is the other file (along with promptForPhotsetName.cs) that was created when I added the Custom Control:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Photrax">

    <Style TargetType="local:promptForPhotosetName">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:promptForPhotosetName">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <ListBox >
                            <ListBoxItem>
                                <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Image Source="Windows 8.jpg" Height="200" Width="300" Stretch="Fill"></Image>
                                    <Image Source="Windows_8.jpg" Height="200" Width="300"   Stretch="Fill"></Image>
                                    <Image Source="windows8(1).jpg" Height="200" Width="300"   Stretch="Fill">
                                    </Image>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </ListBoxItem>
                        </ListBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Yet I get this error: *The name "promptForPhotosetName" does not exist in the namespace "using:Photrax"."* on both this line of XAML:

```
<Style TargetType="local:promptForPhotosetName">
```

...and this one:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="local:promptForPhotosetName">
```

Why? The class *promptForPhotosetName* IS indeed in the Photrax namespace!

Comment: What the Hec Ramsey!? With no changes to the code, I went back and compiled after posting this, and it compiled fine. Were the compiler gerbils taking a siesta or, worse yet, ingesting mind-altering substances earlier, or what?

Comment: Maybe you you didn't click 'compile' hard enough the first time?

Comment: I wrote too soon - now the err msg is back again...but only on the second spot now!!! (the ControlTemplate line)...??? If I remove that second one atogether (the "TargetType" bit), it compiles fine again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like just the design tools error. Rebuilding the project should make the designer recognize the types it hasn't seen before.

Comment: So this is a known issue? The gerbils should be put on notice that they can be replaced.